# Transaction not active exception - EJB Transaction State

Tags: java, transactions, jboss, ejb, transactionmanager

I am having a problem with EJB components that are responsible for starting a transaction.
I am using Jboss 5.01.

Basically I would like to execute a given code after a specific transaction was committed. the specific code also involves calling an EJB component which makes it's own transactions.

To make sure that my code is executed after a previous transaction is committed I've registered a 
Synchronization component into a transaction component :

```
Transaction tx = transactionManager.getTransaction();
tx.registerSynchronization(new CallbackSynchronization());
```

The `Synchronizaton` implementation basically does the following:

```
class CallbackSynchronization implements Synchnronization {

    private AccountService service;  // This is a Stateless session bean

    public CallbackSynchronization(AccountService service) {
        this.service   = service;
    }

    public afterCompletion(int status) {
        if(Status.STATUS_COMMITTED == status) {
            service.deleteAccounts();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I call the `service.deleteAccounts()` I get an exception that eventually tells me that the transaction is not active.

And this is what confuses me. an EJB with methods marked with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` will create a new transaction if one is not active(the REQUIRED is the default in JBOSS).

Why then am I getting "Transaction not active" ?

Many Thanks,

Yaniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the original transaction that you started is still associated with the thread (even though it is in a COMMITTED status). One of the significant differences between using the [Transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html) and the [TransactionManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html) is that the later's [commit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html#commit%28%29) and [rollback()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html#rollback%28%29) methods will unassociate the transaction from the thread. To quote from the javadoc for both methods:

> When this method completes, the thread is no longer associated with a
>   transaction.

There's two ways to deal with this (and I am outlining them in a very raw manner which you may want to refine a bit).

Option 1: Issue a rollback or commit against the transaction manager (in a try block because it will fail).

```
public afterCompletion(int status) {
  if(Status.STATUS_COMMITTED == status) {
    try { transactionManager.rollback(); } catch (Throwable t) {}
    service.deleteAccounts();
  }
}
```

Option 2: Start a new transaction, which will satisfy the REQUIRED attribute of your EJB by pre-starting a transaction, but you need to stick around and manage it which gets sticky.

```
public afterCompletion(int status) {
  if(Status.STATUS_COMMITTED == status) {
    try { 
      transactionManager.begin();
      service.deleteAccounts();
      transactionManager.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ... handle exception here
    }
  }
}
```

Option 3: The cleanest option may be to mark the EJB method as **REQUIRES_NEW** as this will force the EJB container to start a new transaction.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, to make things cleaner I've decided to send a JMS message which will trigger the next EJB call.